# cannot transform type bson.Raw to a BSON Document: length read exceeds number of bytes available

Tags: mongodb, go

Trying to add some json data from an API to a database but get this error when trying

`cannot transform type bson.Raw to a BSON Document: length read exceeds number of bytes available. length=259839 bytes=1919951`

I know the json is well below mongodb limit of 16mb, ive even tried importing just some small data from [this api](http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json) but get the same error. I was able to import just a test struct to see it was working but my api data doesnt seem to be going through. Is there some type of conversion i need to do with my api data? Here is my golang code

```
func main(i int) {

    url := "http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json"

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    // _ = body
    log.Println(string(body))


    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-slmxe.mongodb.net/dbtest?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

    // Connect to MongoDB
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Connected to database")

    collection := client.Database("dbtest").Collection("test")

    insertResult, err := collection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Inserted", insertResult.InsertedID)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your json with bson.D to able to send the data to Mongodb. This is to build representation for native go types. Example below:

```
// insert the document {name: "Alice"}
res, err := coll.InsertOne(context.TODO(), bson.D{{"name", "Alice"}})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Please refer to following documentation:
https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.3.4/mongo?tab=doc#Collection.InsertOne

Comment: I have JSON encoded data(type []byte) how can i import it to Mongo?